# Angular I want validation on my string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

Hello I have one input box here I enter 10 digit string so I want following validation on that entered string

1. First 4 letter should be alphabet
2. 5 to 9 letter should be numeric and
3. Last 10 letter should be alphabet

Is there any validation process for this

**For example**

String should be **ABBC12345A**

It is valid string so how I add validation on input box in my angular

Comment: use a regex ...

Comment: @Pierre Emmanuel Lallemant  You have any pattern

Comment: It should be like to this `/^([a-zA-Z]){4}([0-9]){5}([a-zA-Z]){1}$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 /^([a-zA-Z]){4}([0-9]){5}([a-zA-Z]){1}$/
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, you can use regex. There are a few options, this is the way I like do do it.

```
/^(\w){4}(\d){5}(\w){1}$/
```

- `^` start of string
- `\w` matches any alpha character
- `\d` matches any digit
- `{x}` forces it to be x instances
- `$` end of string

Example: https://regex101.com/r/kPCRql/1

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
<input [ngControl]="fullName" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]*">
```

And here is the documentation for your reference on regex
[https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp](http://regex%20document)